# Total number of rows under percentage value

Tags: dax

I have created a measure that shows gross profit and works ok.  I would like to use this and count the number of times the GP is less than 10%

I have tried to create a formula but I am new to dax, I thought I could use the IF function and say 1 or 0 if it was under or over and then use the count function.

```
count(
if(
    (
    sum(FJ[Bill]) - sum(FJ[Cost]) 
    )
    / sum(FJ[Bill]) < 10,1,0)

)
```

When validating I am getting the error Parameter is not the correct type.

Comment: Can you please include 10 cases of sample data and show what you get with your measure? So we can recreate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Dax can apply a filter on the table that you want to use and perform calculation on this filtered table.

Use the fonction calculate to do this type of calculation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax

The easiest way to do this is to add a column with Gross profit for each row and count the row filtered by 10%

Your column :

```
GP = (Sheet2[FJ[Bill]]]-Sheet2[FJ[cost]]]) / Sheet2[FJ[Bill]]]
```

Your new measure will be like this :

```
Measure 2 = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Sheet2),and(Sheet2[GP] < 0.1,Sheet2[GP] >= 0 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

after some digging and trial and error I believe this is the solution for me.  I didn't want to add a calculated column.

```
COUNTROWS(
Filter(FJ, sum(FJ[Bill]) - Sum(FJ[Cost]) / sum(FJ[Bill]) <0.1)
)
```